# CMS for User Generated Content

Tags: content-management-system, user-generated-content

I'm building a site where users can post links (to webpages, Youtube videos, product pages on Amazon, images from Facebook) or upload media - under specific categories which have been defined by me.

I'm not sure if WordPress will work best because I don't want my users (many of them won't be WP users) to see the dashboard, multiple things on WordPress after logging in. Ideally, I want them to see just the prompts for attributes I define for different post types and nothing more.

I have been looking at custom WP posts but they still have the potential to scare off my target user base.
I have never worked with Joomla. Not that I have worked with WP but I'm sure I can follow tutorials.

My users will be creating a showcase of the content they add - maybe like Pinterest.

I will need to build some APIs to add content from other applications once the user allows access to them.

Considering these requirements, should I sweat it out with WP or is there an alternate CMS?